# jquery click a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, href

I have an  element that has a href attribute calling a javascript function. This element is in two classes : ( `class="icon32 icon-close"` ). This link is represented as an "X" on a div that has the class `.modal` and is used to close the `div`.
My question is, can I make the div close, therefore, calling the a link, when the user presses the "esc" key. I tried the code below, but it does NOT work, although the alert shows up:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        alert('esc was pressed');

        $('.modal>.icon32').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: but it does work ?? or it doesn't work..

Comment: Shouldn't jQuery UI Dialog already take care of handling the Esc?

Comment: Let's see the relevant HTML and JavaScript for the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Try to use `keydown` instead of `keypress`

Comment: try $('div.modal .icon32').click();

Comment: @peter it should work, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdv29/). Can you post the code for that "X" link? EDIT: see my answer. :)

Comment: When replying to comments also please use `@` to notify otherwise we won't see your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling the `.click()` event of **the native DOM element** not the jQuery `.click()` event. To do that, have such code instead:

```
$('.modal>.icon32')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use keyup or keydown for the escape key, and `e.which` is normalized in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 27) {
            $('.modal > .icon32').trigger('click'); //NOTE: direct child selector
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TVdN4/)

Answer (score 0):

which doesn't work - pressing the esc key (in which case try using e.which instead of keyCode), or the actual selector to invoke the click? (in which case, test if your selector is wrong by giving the element an explicit ID and try selecting it that way to verfy that it's just your selector).

Also, why do you need to "click" the "X" ->Can you not just "hide()" the modal div element?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this :

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        // As soon as he escape is clicked you do..
        $('.icon32.icon-close').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery modal dialog, use option `closeOnEscape: false` like this:

```
$("#div").dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                       //do something
                    }
                    Cancel: function(){
                       //do something
                    }
                }
            });
```